# Spring initBinder not invoking CustomDateEditor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I am trying to bind string input form parameter to the date property of a bean using following code. 
I want to bind the date formatter
only to a specific property named `registrationDate` of the bean `User`. I have tried various ways to specify the field name
`registrationDate` in a call to `binder.registerCustomEditor` but `CustomDateEditor` never get's called.

`CustomDateEditor` works 
only if i drop the field name from `binder.registerCustomEditor` call and make it global for all date fields as demonstrated by
the last commented line in the `initBinderAll()` method in the controller below. 
Hope someone points me in the right direction.

user.jsp :-

```
<form:form action="/some_url" modelAttribute="user">
    <input type="text" id="registrationDate" name="registrationDate" value="${regDate}" />
</form:form>
```

User.java :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Column(name = "reg_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date registrationDate;
}
```

UserController.java :-

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/some_url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleSubmission(
            @ModelAttribute("user")@Valid User user, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinderAll(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "user.registrationDate", new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM"), false));

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "User.registrationDate", new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM"), false));

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "registrationDate", new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM"), false));

        //binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM"), true));
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. `binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "dob", new CustomDateEditor(
    dateFormat, false));` works ok for me. The only thing rhat I can think of what might be causing this is if **Note: Only one single registered custom editor per property path is supported. In the case of a Collection/array, do not register an editor for both the Collection/array and each element on the same property.** from docs

Comment: Hello Arun, unfortunately it's not working in my case. And there is only one custom editor for property 'registrationDate' in my case. The content of initBinderAll() method is exactly what i posted in the OP.

Comment: Have you tryed the annotation based way with `@DateTimeFormat` that use the Type Conversion API introduced in Spring 3.0, insted of the old PropertyEditor.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralph. It works. You saved me a lot of trouble. If you can post your comment as an answer i will go ahead and accept it.